# Cannot split URL, showing as System.object[]

Tags: javascript

I am declaring the current URL variable as

```
var vFullURL = (document.URL);
```

This is added to the table with the correct URL string.

When I then try the following:

```
var vURL = vFullURL.split("/");
```

or

```
var vURL = vFullURL.toString.split("/");
```

The URL returns as `System.Object[]`

Does anyone know how I can split the URL?

Comment: What are your expected results? Also what are you trying to accomplish?  The string `split` function returns an array of substrings.  You are splitting the values correctly... now what are trying to do with the values after you split them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `toString()` after you split it, not before.

```
var vFullURL = document.URL;
var vURL = vFullURL.split('/').toString();
```

Results in (for this page, as example): `"http:,,stackoverflow.com,questions,27786939,javascript-cannot-split-sharepoint-url-showing-as-system-object,27787020#27787020"`

Comment: Thanks Antiga!! I knew it was going to be something simple.Bad syntax strikes again!!